# Find line number of a phrase in a file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file that looks like this (only a small section):

```
õ õ ø         ø õ ø         ø ø ø         ø ø ø         ø ø ø         ø ø Øó         ø Øó Ùó         õ     Ïó ø         ø Ïó Ðó         ø Ðó ø         ø Ðó Öó         ø Öó Øó         rö sö ø         ø sö ø           ø ø ø         ø ø ø         ø ø ø         ø ø  ø         ø  ø !ø         !ø  ø "ø         !ø "ø #ø           #ø "ø $ø         #ø $ø %ø         %ø $ø &ø         %ø &ø 'ø         'ø &ø (ø         'ø (ø )ø         )ø (ø   *ø         )ø *ø +ø         +ø *ø ,ø         +ø ,ø -ø         -ø ,ø .ø         -ø .ø /ø         /ø .ø 0ø           /ø 0ø 1ø         1ø 0ø 2ø         1ø 2ø 3ø         3ø 2ø 4ø         3ø 4ø 5ø         5ø 4ø 6ø         5ø 6ø   7ø         7ø 6ø 8ø         7ø 8ø 9ø         9ø 8ø :ø         9ø :ø ;ø         ;ø :ø <ø         ;ø <ø =ø           =ø <ø >ø         ) 
End of Binary Section   2013)    
(0 "Zone variables:")
```

I found a snippet that looks like this:

```
f = open('D:/bat_new.msh','rb')
line_num = 0
search_phrase = '(0 "Zone variables:")'

for line in f.readlines():
    line_num += 1
    if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
        print line_num
```

When I run above snippet, I get the line number 30308, but if I open the file in Notepad++, the line number is 60533.

Can anyone help out on this?

Ultimately, I want to skip reading the stuff above this line and only read the entries below it.

Comment: `find` will return the lowest index that it finds the given phrase. So you don't need to iterate through the lines using a for loop.

Comment: you probably have `(0 "Zone variables:")` at line 30308 too; may your data be written with little modifications twice, as 30308 is roughly 60533/2?

Comment: It's possible that this is a Windows text file (except for the binary bits), so Windows apps like Notepad++ are only counting Windows newlines—that is, `\r\n`—while your code, which opens the file in binary mode, is counting all raw newlines—that is, `\n`. So, if there are 30308 `\r\n`s plus another 30225 `\n` without `\r`, this is exactly what you'd find.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the `readlines` here; you can just do `for line in f:` instead. And if you do it that way, besides being shorter and more readable, you also avoid needing to read the entire file into memory before you can start doing any work on it.

Comment: As another side note, instead of counting up `line_num` manually like this, just do `for line_num, line in enumerate(f):`.

Comment: Finally, it looks like this file is in some kind of format that makes it possible to detect and skip over sections. If so, you might be better off writing a trivial parser for that format than trying to count line numbers.

Comment: Ok, I see. WelI, I know that there are no entries of this phrase after the one I'm looking for, so essentially I want to make sure that I get the line number of the last entry if it occurs several times in the binary section (basically I want to read the last 200 lines or so of the file). 

Everything I want to read is in clear text, so a follow up question is why I have to use rb for reading? Using r gives no result. 

Thanks for helping out!
Tobbe

Comment: Abarnert, thanks a lot for your valuable input. Will look into your suggestions tomorrow (getting late here now)

Answer (score 2):

Without actually having access to the file, there's no way to tell you what's going on, except to guess.

But I have a guess I'd give about 2:1 odds on.

Windows text files use the two-character sequence `\r\n` for newlines. Python binary-mode files use the single-character sequence `\n`.

When you're dealing with actual text files, it doesn't make a big difference if you count this wrong—each `\r\n` is exactly one `\n`, and there won't be any other `\n` characters in the file, so you'll get the same count as Notepad++.

But your files have embedded binary data. If the data were totally random, 1/256th of the characters would be a bare `\n`, but only 1/65536th of the two-character sequences would be a `\r\n`. Obviously, from your snippet, the data aren't totally random. But it's still likely that your code will find a lot more `\n` characters than Notepad++ finds `\r\n` sequences.

Comment: Agreed on the `'\r\n'` issue being likely.